# Ember: How to make POST request using href

Tags: ember.js

I have `href` that contains GET request. It is doing export of some data to csv file and it works well. By clicking on the link particular service returns csv file that appears in downloads.

hbs:

```
<a {{bind-attr href=csvExportUri}}><span class="fooicon-excel"></span></a>
```

js:

```
app.FooController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  csvExportUri: function () {
        var opts = this.model.options;
        return '/bar/csv?' + $.param(options);
  }.property('model')
```

My question is how to modify code so `href` will represent POST request? I need it because my `param` became too big.

Thank you

Comment: you can't. an `<a>` can only ever generate a `GET` request. If you want a `POST`, you have to use a `<form method="post">`, or use JS to intercept the click on the `<a>` and generate a post programatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a raw ajax request to try and accomplish what you are doing:

hbs:

```
<a {{action 'exportToCsv'}}><span class="fooicon-excel">Export To CSV</span></a>
```

js:

```
App.FooController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
    exportToCsv: function() {
      Ember.$.ajax({
        url: '/bar/csv',
        data: JSON.stringify({ foo: 'bar', options: someOptionsObj }),
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        headers: {
          token: 'sometoken',
        },
      }).then(function(apiResult) {
        // do something with apiResult
        // possiblly open download link that is in apiResult
      });
    }
  }
});
```

- note that this is a raw jQuery ajax call so any of these options can be used in the Ember.$.ajax fn: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/